# How to use the semicolon in sentences

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

I am a mathematics student and not a native English speaker. There is something that has always been unclear to me. I am writing an essay right now and I want to construct the following sentence:

> "This is best understood in the following way; when considering the *k*th product we can either choose to produce it or not."

Is the semicolon here correct?. I know for sure that I do not like the idea of placing a full stop there because it does not feel right. However, I am not sure at all if this is correct as it is. If anyone can correct me or confirm that it is correct that would be great.

Comment: quick, non-explanatory answer: you should use a colon there, not a semi-colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a colon here, because it tells the reader that the second statement describes a consequence of the first.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the answer. When would you use the semicolon then?

Comment: @Slugger - You can think of it as a kind of intermediate punctuation mark that (to varying degrees, depending on the context) combines some of the characteristics of comma, period/full stop and colon. Take a look at the usage notes on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon#Usage) for more detailed discussion regarding how and when to use it.